# Accessing a Hash table as a Value-Sorted Range in D

Tags: sorting, range, hashtable, d

If I have a hash-table `File[string] _subs` and want to access its values in a sorted way is there a better way than simply through

```
auto ssubs = new File[_subs.length]; // preallocate sorted subs
size_t ix = 0;
foreach (sub; _subs) {
    ssubs[ix++] = sub;  // set new reference to sub
}

ssubs.sort!((a, b) => (a.timeLastModified >
                       b.timeLastModified));
return ssubs;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to skip the foreach-loop and use `.values`, like so:

```
auto ssubs = _subs.values.sort!((a, b) => (a.timeLastModified > b.timeLastModified));
```

I think it's better to not add dependencies between elements (like with a for-loop), when they don't need it. The reason for this is that it's easier to make the code parallel without it.

Comment: See also `.byValue` mentioned here: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/irtioegsnkdimdzklbtj@forum.dlang.org

Answer (score 3):

If you find yourself doing that operation often, consider trying a `RedBlackTree` from [std.container](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_container.html#.redBlackTree). It's the usual sortedness vs. runtime complexity tradeoff: Whereas accessing and inserting elements into an unordered hashmap (hashset) like an AA is O(1), the same operations on an ordered map (set) like a RedBlackTree is O(log(n)).